# Using AngularJS $filter with ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got an object in my `$scope` that contains a bunch of details about, say, an election. This object includes a `voters` array of objects, each with an `_id`:

```
$scope.election = {
  voters: [
    { _id: '123' },
    { _id: '456' },
    { _id: '789' }
  ]
}
```

Also in my scope I have details about the currently logged in user:

```
$scope.user = { _id: '456' }
```

How can I bind [ng-disabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angDisabled) to the presence of `$scope.user._id` in the array of objects `$scope.voters`?

**What I've Tried**

I have success simply *displaying* the presence of `$scope.user._id` in `$scope.election.voters` like this (Jade syntax):

```
pre(ng-bind="election.voters | filter:{user._id} | json")
```

When the current user *is* among the `voters`, they get displayed. When they're *not* among the voters, I get an empty array. That seems quite close to what I want.

But using the same filter (sans `| json`) with ng-disabled, I get the Angular [Infinite $digest loop](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24rootScope%3ainfdig) error.

Is this situation too complicated? Should I move it to a `$filter`? If so, how would I go about making it generic enough to be useful in a number of situations (if that's even feasible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can run a simple filter right in controller, or using `app.filter('filterName', func...)` create a custom filter you can use in markup

```
$scope.userIsVoter = function() {
        return $scope.election.voters.filter(function(el) {
          return el._id == $scope.user._id;
        }).length
      }
```

```
<button ng-disabled="userIsVoter()">Do Something</button>
```

Comment: This seems like the way to go, but I'm running into a complication. My `$scope.election` is actually set as the result of a Restangular call. `$scope.userIsVoter()` gets called before the call finishes, and needs to be checked again by Angular afterwards. Can I trigger that check, or would the approach need to change?

Comment: can set a $watch for voters, use a scope variable for `ng-disabled` and set that variable within the watch `$disabledVariable= $scope.userIsVoter()`